# IE input:file over button

Tags: internet-explorer, file-upload

I'm trying to create a picture uploader for a website with ajax and it is not working in IE (any version)

I have a button setup that call's the input:File on a trigger.
then the input:file, if not empty, will send the form to a iframe

the form is hidden(because it is ugly (: )

Problem is this: When i press the input dirrectly, it works #1, but when i press the button, it doesnt go all the way

When i run it with the button, it doesnt go further than the $('#upload_target').load() line.

here is the code

**HTML**

```
<button id="addheader" type="button" class="btn btn-success span2">Add</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger span2" onclick="removeAllHeader()">Remove all</button>
<form id="formheader" class="" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>ajax_admin/addHeader" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target">
    <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<iframe id="upload_target" class="hidden" name="upload_target" hidden></iframe>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function addHeader(){
$("#addheader").click(function(){
    $("#uploaded_file").trigger('click');
});

$("#formheader input:file").change(function (){

    if($("#formheader input:file").val() != ""){
        $("#formheader input:submit").trigger('click');
    }
 });

$('#formheader').submit(function(){

    $('#upload_target').load( function(){
      var imgid = $('#upload_target').contents().find('#fileid').html();
      var imgname = $('#upload_target').contents().find('#filename').html();
      var imgdate = $('#upload_target').contents().find('#filedate').html();

      if (imgname){
        $(".list-pictures").append('<tr class="header-row" id="header-num'+imgid+'"> \
                <td class="span3"><img width="200" height="50" alt="'+imgname+'" src="'+$("#base_url").text()+'tools/media/header/'+imgname+'" class="img-polaroid image-header"></td> \
                <td class="span3"><p>'+imgdate+'</p></td> \
                <td class="span1"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeHeader(this,'+imgid+')">Remove</button></td> \
            </tr> \
            ')
        $('#upload_target').contents().find('#filename').remove();

      }
    });
});

}
```

Comment: Have you tried watching what happens with the F12 Tools' JavaScript debugger enabled?

Comment: yes after searching i found out that it doesnt send the information to my iframe... but i dont know why... my button only triggers the input, it does nothing else, but when i press the input dirrectly it works...